# How to pass in a map "created on the way" in a go template

Tags: html, go, templates, go-templates

I want to make something like a UI component 100% reusable in Go templates but i don't know if it's possible to do it. So I'm trying to do the next:

```html
{{define "components/menu-button"}}
<a href="{{.link}}" class="text-white">{{.content}}</a>
{{end}}
```

This is my component, it expect a `map` because of the properties are in lowercase.

And then in my homepage I have this little menu that uses 3 times the `components/menu-button` component in my navbar:

```html
<div class="hidden gap-4 sm:flex">
    {{template "components/menu-button" {"link": "/contact", "content": "Contact"}}}
    {{template "components/menu-button" {"link": "/docs", "content": "Docs"}}}
    {{template "components/menu-button" {"link": "/download", "content": "Download"}}}
</div>
```

But I don't know if I can in some way create a `map` like I'm doing up here in the example, it's like JSON thing but well I tried.

By the way, it gives me the next error:

```
unexpected "{" in template clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of syntax is not supported by Go's templates.

What you can do is declare a custom function, e.g.

```golang
func MakeMap(kvs ...any) map[any]any {
    m := make(map[any]any)
    for i := 0; i < len(kvs)-1; i+=2 {
        m[kvs[i]] = kvs[i+1]
    }
    return m
}
```

Then you can make the function available to the templates by using [`(*Template).Funcs`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.21.0#Template.Funcs), e.g.

```golang
t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"M":MakeMap})
```

Then, inside the template, you can invoke the function using the key `M`.

```html
{{template "components/menu-button" (M "link" "/contact" "content" "Contact")}}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Sl1ON-z7Mtn